# Use binwalk to extract all files

Tags: linux, extract, steganography, hexdump

I have a file `music.mp3`. After using `binwalk`, I get the result:

```
pexea12@DESMICE:~/Downloads$ binwalk music.mp3

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
152318        0x252FE         MySQL ISAM compressed data file Version 2
586865        0x8F471         MySQL ISAM compressed data file Version 5
5669358       0x5681EE        MySQL ISAM index file Version 1
5831936       0x58FD00        TIFF image data, little-endian offset of first image directory: 8
5832467       0x58FF13        Unix path: /www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
5832624       0x58FFB0        Unix path: /purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
5832748       0x59002C        Unix path: /ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/"
5832806       0x590066        Unix path: /ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/sType/ResourceEvent#">
```

I realize that there are some other file type in my `music.mp3` such as MySQL, TIFF image. Now I want to extract all these files to see the real contents of them.

I try the command `binwalk -e music.mp3` but it only works with compressed files such as .zip. How can I get all these files?

Answer (score 63):

You can use the following command:

```
binwalk --dd='.*' music.mp3
```

Answer (score 28):

```
binwalk -e music.mp3
```

will automatically list/extract known file types, WHERE AS

```
binwalk -D='.*' music.mp3
```

OR

```
binwalk --dd='.*' music.mp3
```

will extract all files.

From the [manual](https://manpages.org/binwalk):

> -D, --dd=<type[:ext[:cmd]]>  Extract <type> signatures (regular expression), give the files an extension of <ext>, and execute <cmd>

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
binwalk -e -c music.mp3
```

default directory would be your `pwd`